# Kotlin: change the type MutableList<java.util.HashMap<Int, Int>> to kotlin.collections.HashMap<Int, Int>

Tags: list, kotlin, collections, hashmap

I would like to learn Kotlin and try to transfer multiple objects that each manage two ints to one list that manages a hashmap of two ints.
This is the new object:

```
public class HashObject(val maps: MutableList<HashMap<Int, Int>>){  
    ...  
}
```

This is the old object:

```
public class OldObject(  
    val a: Int,  
    val b: Int  
)
```

I have a list of the old objects:

```
val oldObjects: List<OldObject> = ...
```

And i am trying to transfer it like this:

```
val hashObjects = mutableListOf<HashMap<Int, Int>>()  
for(obj in oldObjects){  
   hashObjects.add(hashMapOf(obj.a to obj.b))    
val result = HashObject(maps = hashObjects)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch.
    Required: kotlin.collections.HashMap<Int, Int> /* = java.util.HashMap<Int, Int> */
    Found: MutableList<java.util.HashMap<Int, Int>>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you declared HashObject this way? `public class HashObject(val maps: MutableList<HashMap<Int, Int>>)` Because the error says it was expecting just a single HashMap. Can you verify specifically what line the error occurs on?

Comment: You are right. The project has become a bit cluttered and I thought that a collection in Kotlin is something for storing multiple objects. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do what you're asking is

```
val result = oldObjects.map { oldObj -> hashMapOf(oldObj.a to oldObj.b) }
    .toMutableList()
```

Answer (score 0):

The question seems a bit confused, but I suspect that what's really needed is a single map from Int to Int. One of the simplest (and most efficient) ways to get that is:

```
val result = oldObjects.associate{ it.a to it.b }
```

That gives a `Map<Int, Int>`, with one entry for each of the original OldObjects. (With the caveat that if multiple OldObjects have the same key, only the last will be included in the result. If you need to preserve them all in that case, then a map isn't the right structure.)

(If you need the result to be mutable, you can then call `toMutableMap()` on it — but in general it's simpler and safer to stick to immutable objects where possible.)